# How to get this Joomla Module to work correctly?

Tags: php, joomla, module

I had to move/copy a site onto a different TLD. The only thing I did not manage to get it to work was a module used on the homepage to display the latest news.

This is how the site should look: http://www.sednagroup.it/
... and this is how it looks: http://www.sednagroup.ro/

That sidebar with the image and excerpt. I can't get it to work.
Here's the module if it helps:

```
<?php // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>
<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
<li class="latestnews<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="latestnews<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
        <?php echo $item->text; ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you move or copy it?

The new site (`.ro`) is showing the expected output from the code, i.e. the title of the article wrapped in a link to the article — in fact in looks like the standard module that ships with Joomla! 1.5.x. (I'll assume 1.5 as you haven't specified your Joomla! version).

The original site (`.it`) is showing additional content, probably the content before the "[Read More](http://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_an_Article_into_an_introduction_with_a_link_to_read_more)" (if one exists).

Which probably means that a [template module override](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides) for the module has been created or someone has changed the core module files (*bad idea by the way*). I would start by:

1. Looking for override files in the `template/yourtemplate/` directory
2. If you can't find an override for `mod_latestnews` compare the `.it` `modules/mod_latestnews/` with the same directory on `.ro`

Finally if you do find that core files have been hacked may I suggested that you actually duplicate the `mod_latestnews` and rename it to something like `mod_latestnews_extended` rather than hacking the core in your `.ro` site.

Comment: Well when I copied the site I did just that, copy the files, the database and then translated the posts accordingly. I really thought there would be no difference..

Comment: Akeeba's Backup and restore process is by far the safest, it also looks after things like DB credentials, `/tmp` & `/cache` paths and lots of other things that can cause issues.